# Create Correlogram Using Harman23 Data Set

Tags: r, visualization, ggcorrplot

One of my questions for an assignment is asking me to create a Correlogram using the cov variable from the Harman23 data set, which is included in the ggplot2 package. Though I keep getting errors for not supplying x and y but the only examples given to me by my professor show him writing `ggcorrplot(cor(data), type="lower", lab=TRUE)` for example.

Here are some of the commands I've tried so far.

```r
> Harman23 = Harman23.cor
> ggcorrplot(cor(Harman23), type="lower", lab=TRUE)
Error in cor(Harman23) : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
> ggcorrplot(cor(Harman23, x=Harman23$cov), type="lower", lab=TRUE)
Error in cor(Harman23, x = Harman23$cov) : 'y' must be numeric
```

Comment: since it is an assignment I will give a hint, what type of object is Harman23.cor? would cor work on that object

Comment: also please provide the packages you are using

Comment: I figured it out by assigning the cov variable from the dataset to its own variable then supplying it as the matrix. I am going to put it as an answer, thank you though!!! @Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> cov = Harman23.cor$cov
>ggcorrplot(cor(cov),type="lower", lab=TRUE)
```